# How to write Inline If Statement(SQL IIF) in EFCore Select?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following `Customer` table:

```
Id  First    Last   LocationId
0   John     Doe    2
1   Mary     Smith  4
```

My use case requires column level permissions(predicated on a value in the Entity's table).

How can I query like the following thru EFCore?

```sql
SELECT Id, First, IIF(LocationId in(2), Last, '') FROM Customer;
```

Whereby `Last` is returned only when `LocationId == 2`.

- Can this be accomplished in Linq-to-Entities as a dynamic type?
- If not, can I use `FromSql()` and [`QueryTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types)?
- I found this SO [How to create “inline if statement” with expressions in dynamic select for null checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873765/how-to-create-inline-if-statement-with-expressions-in-dynamic-select-for-null).  But I am not familiar with `Expression` type.  This implies its possible however.

Comment: Why would you do that in SQL?  It seems like the difficulties in implementing it in SQL (EF specifically) could easily be replaced by the caller.

Comment: `IIF` is basically a syntactic sugar for `CASE` expression... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560686/how-can-i-achieve-sql-case-statement-from-linq

Comment: Why not just use the C# ternary operator `?:` ? (`from c in Customer select new { c.Id, c.First, Last = (new[] { 2 }.Contains(c.LocationId) ? c.Last : "") }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking to use the .Select() method and ternary operator. So something like this:

```
context.Customer.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.First, Last = c.LocationId == 2 ? c.Last : "" });
```

Comment: Sweet!,  Thank you.  I feel ignorant for missing that.  Also thanks to @NetMage